# Custom button with style of NavigationBar back button

Tags: uibutton, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to make a custom button that looks like a back button in NavigationBar? I mean the shape of the left side that is like an arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. You will have to draw it yourself to an image file and set it as a background to your custom button.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thnx